# Простой вопрос. Почему вызывается функция даже когда я её не вызываю?

Tags: c

Этот код призван вызывать функцию s() каждый раз когда я нажимаю клавишу s. Но вместо этого функция s() вызывается постоянно:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void s() {
    printf("What?");
}

int main(void) {
    char control;
    while(1) { 
        control = getch();
        if(control = 's') {
            s();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if(control == 's')` вы присвоить `=` вместо сравнить `==` написали

Comment: Спасибо большое. Просто прекрасно.

Comment: Ага, вы еще как ее вызываете сами) не путайте присвоение = и проверку на равенство ==

Comment: По видимому я до сих пор это путаю. И в си это фатально.

Comment: >вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечаткой.
-> Да, в принципе я точно не обижусь если снесут. Он может не нести пользу.

Answer (score 3):

От подобных ошибок спасает "[нотация Йоды](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%99%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B)". Вот это скомпилируется. Может и с руганью (зависит от компилятора и его настроек), но скомпилируется:

```
if( control = 's' )
```

А вот это не скомпилируется в принципе:

```
if( 's' = control )
```

Comment: С современными компиляторами обратная нотация не нужна, они выдают предупреждение.

Comment: не всегда. Лучше явно компилятору передать `-pedantic -Wall -Werror`. Сколько багов я не пустил в прод благодаря этому.

Нотация Йоды не нужна - она ужасна.

Comment: @VladD, не так часто можно встретить относитльно большие  исходники, которые молча собираются хотя бы при `-Wall -pedantic`. Поэтому многие просто забивают смотреть на предупреждения :(

Comment: а потом "ой, у нас баги", "нужно больше тестировать", "нужны статические анализаторы кода" и тому подобное.

Comment: @KoVadim, так это уже "потом".  Я часто собираю какие-то приблуды из исходников  - там столько вылезает... Даже простенький как 2 копейки `cadaver` и то выдаёт немало. А анализаторы всё равно нужны :) Тот же `cppcheck` неплохо отлавливает всякие мелочи, про которые компилятор молчит.

Comment: @PinkTux: Эээ? У нас в проекте стоит опция treat warnings as errors. Проект **должен** собираться без предупреждений, каждое предупреждение — потенциальный баг, который намного лучше отловить сразу, чем потом из тестов и крешей у юзера. А если собирать чужой код — ну так там автор ответственен за качество.

Comment: @VladD, это понятно, что для каждого проекта можно свои ключи настроить. Но - лень :) У меня просто алиасы для gcc и g++ прописаны со всеми ключами,  и как раз из-за необходимости собирать чужое к ним не добавшь `-Werror` . Хотя надо бы пересмотреть, да...

Comment: @PinkTux: Ну, можно добавить в стандартный makefile, например? Чужой проект придёт со своим makefile'ом, по идее.